# Yii Class not found, Namespace usage

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, yii, amazon-s3, namespaces

I have written a S3 uploader file that works in Yii1 but I am trying to implement it into the new Yii2 application. Below are my code structure:

Here is the Error: 
Class 'yii\labworkz\S3\S3' not found

File Location
vendor/labworkz/AWS/S3.php

Content:

```
    namespace yii\labworkz\S3;
    use yii\base\Exception;

    class S3 { 
    ...
    }
```

File: 
controllers/UploadController.php

```
    use yii\labworkz;
    public function actionS3() {
        $s3 = new labworkz\S3\S3( $this->S3_KEY, $this->S3_SECRET );
        if ( isset( $s3 ) ) {
            echo "S3 Connected";
        }
    }
```

I know this seems like littel but its really simple and I am not sure why its not working. Also this is a test function I made for troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

Try to fix your namespace. Like this:

```
namespace yii\labworkz\AWS;
use yii\base\Exception;

class S3 { 
...
}
```

And this:

```
use yii\labworkz;
public function actionS3() {
    $s3 = new labworkz\AWS\S3( $this->S3_KEY, $this->S3_SECRET );
    if ( isset( $s3 ) ) {
        echo "S3 Connected";
    }
}
```

Comment: And your class instantiation should be: `$s3 = new labworkz\AWS\S3( $this->S3_KEY, $this->S3_SECRET );`

Comment: I have updated to the format like you recommended and still am getting Class 'labworkz\AWS\S3' not found

Comment: I think you will have to import your classes. Try this on your controller: `Yii::import('application.vendors.labworkz.*');`.

Comment: Also, you will have to define the path of your namespace: `Yii::setPathOfAlias('labworkz',Yii::getPathOfAlias('application.vendors.labworkz'));`

Comment: Well import() and setPathOfAlias is not part of Yii2 because they use namespaces. 

I was able to get it working by adding require(__DIR__ . '/../vendor/labworkz/AWS/s3.php'); to the web/index.php

Comment: Sorry. I had totally neglected the fact that you were using Yii2. Indeed, even in Yii2, the right way to access your namespace is creating an alias. Take a look at [autoloading concept](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-autoloading.html) and [aliases](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-aliases.html#defining-aliases).